# In electron, BrowserWindow.getFocusedWindow returns null when invoked from dialog.showSaveDialog

Tags: file, dialog, focus, electron

In electron, is there a way to get the current focused window during a call to `dialog.showSaveDialog`? This works fine from within `dialog.showOpenDialog` but returns `null` when done from within `dialog.showSaveDialog`.

This works:

```
  dialog.showOpenDialog(function (filepaths) {
    if(filepaths !== undefined){
      BrowserWindow.getFocusedWindow().send('file-open', filepaths[0])
    }
  });
```

This throws `TypeError: Cannot read property 'send' of null`:

```
dialog.showSaveDialog(options, function (filepath) {
  if (filepath !== undefined) {
    BrowserWindow.getFocusedWindow().send('file-save', filepath)
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Managed to fix this by changing the code to this:

```
const activeWindow = BrowserWindow.getFocusedWindow()

dialog.showSaveDialog(options, function (filepath) {
  if (filepath !== undefined) {
    activeWindow.send('file-save', filepath)
  }
});
```

Still interested in an answer to why it doesn't work otherwise if someone has one.